# How can I make my script loop and check all buttons that are active? vanilla js

Tags: javascript

The buttons already close when you click it again but I can't figure out how to make it check all the other buttons and remove all "active" classes.

Apologies if its a dumb question but thanks anyways.

```js
const openMenuButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');

openMenuButton.forEach(button => {  
  button.addEventListener('click',() => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget);
    swapMenu(modal);
  })
});

function swapMenu(modal) {
  const menuOpen = modal.classList.contains('menu-active');
  if(menuOpen == true) {
    modal.classList.remove('menu-active');
  } else {
    modal.classList.add('menu-active');
  };
}
```

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/oqjz3fgy/5/
This is what im trying to do.
I may have overcomplicated things. I only know basic javascript syntax prior to this.

Comment: I think you over complicated things, i think you could have done it all in EventListener click, simply on click, save target and its state (active or not), reset all buttons, re-apply new only on target. Its hard to say without seeing [mre] witch you should make.

Comment: I tried making an example in jsfiddle. Ill try other ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry if I am wrong or not understand your question. However you can do this.

if your code like this:

```
     <div id = 'modal' or class = 'modal'>
       <button class ='menu-active'>click me </button>
       .....
       .....
     </div>
```

```
    
    function swapMenu(modal) {

       const menuOpen = document.querySelectorAll('#modal button'); // select all active menu
       
       for( let i = 0;i < menuOpen.length;i++){

              if(menuOpen[i].classList.contains("menu-active")){

                  menuOpen[i].classList.remove('menu-active');
              }
              else{
                   menuOpen[i].classList.add('menu-active');
               }
       }
```

Comment: I've tried it with a few tweaks. It manages to loop through the buttons but doesn't add the class. Thanks anyway!